# Are these hadith about mushroom authentic?

Tags: hadith, sunnah, food

I was reading this article - https://iqraa.com/BlogPost?Lang=en&Post_ID=10935

It mentions a few hadith about mushrooms

> The Messenger of Allah (Allah’s peace be upon him) said, “Mushroom is
> a sort of manna which Allah sent to children of Israel. Its water is
> cure for the eyes. (Muslim, Ibn Majah)
>
> Sayiduna Ali (Allah be pleased with him) reports our Prophet (Allah’s
> peace be upon him) as saying, “Mushroom is a good cure for the eyes.”
>
> Anas Ibn Malik (Allah be well pleased with him) reports the Prophet
> (Allah’s peace be upon him) saying, “Jannah laughed and the mushroom
> came out and the earth laughed and its treasures came out.”

I searched for these in sunnah.com and could find reference of the first two hadith, however they mentioned truffles instead of mushroom. Do these hadith apply to other types of mushrooms?

I couldn't find the third hadith anywhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These ahadith are about desert truffles. Extending them to mushrooms is not self-evident.

The first hadith is saheeh as it is present in Bukhari and Muslim, who have aimed to only include authentic narrations.

> الكمأة من المن، وماؤها شفاء للعين
>
> Truffles are like Manna and their water heals eye diseases.
>
> <sup>— [Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:5708) and [Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim:2049b)</sup>

The last hadith is obscure, being found mostly in works on medicine rather than in collections of ahadith, and it is likely weak.

> ضحكت الجنة فأخرجت الكمأة وضحكت الأرض فأخرجت الكبر
>
> Paradise laughed and the truffles came out and the earth laughed and caper came out.
>
> <sup>— [الطب النبوي - أبو نعيم الإصفهاني](https://ia600206.us.archive.org/28/items/waq91111/91111.pdf#page=620)</sup>

Comment: Truffles do indeed heal eye diseases according to [THIS](https://scialert.net/fulltext/?doi=tmr.2016.28.34#:~:text=Truffles%20constitute%20an%20important%20source,et%20al.%2C%202005) source. jazakallah.

Comment: Great answer! Can these ahadith be extended to other types of truffles?